# Getting View's Column Description

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it a way to retrieve the view's column description from the base table (fn_listextendedproperty)?

The following syntax only list down the column name from the view

```
 SELECT *
   FROM sys.columns c
   JOIN sys.views v on c.OBJECT_ID = V.OBJECT_ID
   JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = v.schema_id
                     and V.NAME = 'v_ProductInfo'
```

Comment: Why would the column description be different than that base table, other than derived and/or computed columns?

Comment: i need to document it down. So i would like to have the views column description from the base table and export the result in to a chm format. It will ease the user to to get the column description from the view directly

Comment: What exactly do you need for the column description--name, data type, nullable, anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i got the answer.

```
SELECT VIEW_COLUMN_NAME=c.name,VIEW_CATALOG,VIEW_SCHEMA,VIEW_NAME,TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME, ep.value as 'COLUMN_DESCRIPTION'
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.views vw on c.OBJECT_ID = vw.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = vw.schema_id
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE vcu on vw.name = vcu.VIEW_NAME and s.name = vcu.VIEW_SCHEMA and c.name = vcu.COLUMN_NAME
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT distinct SCM_Name=SCM.Name,TBL_Name=TBL.name,COLName=COL.name,COL_Object_id= COL.object_id,COL_column_id=COL.column_id
    FROM
    SYS.COLUMNS COL
    INNER JOIN SYS.TABLES TBL on COL.object_id = TBL.object_id
    INNER JOIN SYS.SCHEMAS SCM ON TBL.schema_id = SCM.schema_id) tempTBL on tempTBL.TBL_Name=vcu.TABLE_NAME and tempTBL.SCM_Name=TABLE_SCHEMA and tempTBL.COLName = vcu.COLUMN_NAME
Left join sys.extended_properties ep on tempTBL.COL_Object_id = ep.major_id and tempTBL.COL_column_id = ep.minor_id
where vw.NAME = 'v_ProductInfo'
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will fail if the view uses two columns from different tables with the same name

something like this:

> Select
>   t1.Id,
>   t2.Id as 'T2Id'
>   From Table1 as t1
>   Inner Join Table2 as t2 On t1.SomeCol=t2.SomeOtherCol

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You may use cte to retrieve the data.

```
Select * from (
    SELECT Row=ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by vw.NAME,Column_id order by Column_id),IEW_COLUMN_NAME=c.name,VIEW_CATALOG,VIEW_SCHEMA,VIEW_NAME,TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME, ep.value as 'COLUMN_DESCRIPTION' 
    FROM sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN sys.views vw on c.OBJECT_ID = vw.OBJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = vw.schema_id
    LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE vcu on vw.name = vcu.VIEW_NAME and s.name = vcu.VIEW_SCHEMA and c.name = vcu.COLUMN_NAME 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT distinct SCM_Name=SCM.Name,TBL_Name=TBL.name,COLName=COL.name,COL_Object_id= COL.object_id,COL_column_id=COL.column_id
        FROM
        SYS.COLUMNS COL
        INNER JOIN SYS.TABLES TBL on COL.object_id = TBL.object_id
        INNER JOIN SYS.SCHEMAS SCM ON TBL.schema_id = SCM.schema_id ) tempTBL on tempTBL.TBL_Name=vcu.TABLE_NAME and tempTBL.SCM_Name=TABLE_SCHEMA and tempTBL.COLName = vcu.COLUMN_NAME 
    Left join sys.extended_properties ep on tempTBL.COL_Object_id = ep.major_id and tempTBL.COL_column_id = ep.minor_id
    --where vw.name = 'vw_avm_allc'
) data
Where Row=1
```